# Where can I find Delphi/Embarcadero redistributables

Tags: delphi-xe5, bpl

Even though I own a few Delphi versions, I got an executable missing, in this case, rtl190.bpl. I started looking for it, and concluded Embarcadero must have a peculiar redistribution policy, nothing like certain "runtime" downloads from  other vendors. Even as a registered developer I don't seem to have rights to any of the downloads for versions I do not own. Are XE5 runtimes, or any other Delphi runtimes, to be found somewhere?

Comment: Runtime packages are not available for separate download. They are only included in the IDE installation. If you have an XE5 app written by someone else, it was their responsibility to either include RTL190 with the app, or else compile the app to not have that dependency.

Answer (score -3):

Apparently only possible source for such missing BPLs are other apps, I found my missing parts in the installation directories of AVG Tune Up and www.wlcsystems.com mscada where the rather rare cc32140mt.dll  was to be found